# Caching async http result in dictionary

Tags: c#, asynchronous, caching, async-await, .net-core

I am wondering what the best way is to retrieve a previously cached object.

The code below works but the bit where the object is fetched from the dictionary looks like it can be done better. I feel like i might be missing something important.

```
public class ResourceProvider
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, string> _cachedResources;

    public async Task<string> GetResource(string url)
    {
        // If there is a cached version use that
        if (_cachedResources.ContainsKey(url))
        {
            // I am not sure this is the proper way if doing it
            return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _cachedResources[url]);
        }

        // Get resource (i know httpclient is better as a static)
        var resource = await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(url);

        _cachedResources.Add(url, resource);

        return resource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just `return _cachedResources[url]);`?

Comment: It seems as simple as that, i did not try that because the return type would be different, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In general I would advice you to use [IMemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.imemorycache?view=aspnetcore-2.0) Interface. Because you can easily switch between in memory cache or an redis cache server (in azure) for example. That's an advantage above an home brew solution.

Usage is quite simple. You simply cache objects by keys. The key has to be unique, like you did in your sample. You can configure absolute or relative 
expiration, priorities and sliding expiration for ever entry how you need it.
It's far better than a simple hashmap.

In this article [How to use caching](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3230129/application-development/how-to-use-in-memory-caching-in-aspnet-core.html) is explained how you setup everthing as a start point.

Answer (score 0):

A task can be awaited as many times as you want. You can do something like this:

```
public class ResourceProvider
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<string>> cachedResources
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ValueTask<string>>();

    public Task<string> GetResource(string url)
        => this.cachedResources.GetOrAdd(url, u => new new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(u));
}
```

Since you it is expected do server the value from cache most of the times, there's now a value task ([ValueTask<TResult> Struct](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask%3CTResult%3E)):

```
public class ResourceProvider
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ValueTask<string>> cachedResources
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ValueTask<string>>();

    public ValueTask<string> GetResource(string url)
        => this.cachedResources.GetOrAdd(
            url,
            u => new ValueTask<string>(new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(u)));
}
```

Comment: What does wrapping of `Task<of string>` instance returned by `GetStringAsync()` in `ValueTask<of string>` add?

Comment: Not much in this particular case, but a good practice for cached values.. [On The Efficiency Of ValueTask](http://blog.i3arnon.com/2015/11/30/valuetask/)

Comment: It's creative but after reading Camilo Terevinto's comment it seems this won't add much and just add unnecessary complexity.